# Issue programmatically removing controls from panel

Tags: c#, collections, controls, panel

I have a form with a panel named pan_items and two buttons named btn_fresh and btn_next. I use 'fresh' to load a set of options and 'next' to change the options. The options are shown as radiobuttons which i  add and remove programmatically. my code adds the radiobutton controls with no problem, but when i try to remove them, it randomly removes some and leaves some. this is my code

```
private void btn_fresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.index = 0;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string str in options[index])
        {
            RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
            rdb.Text = str;
            rdb.Name = str + "_" + i++;
            rdb.Location = new Point(20, i * 20);
            pan_items.Controls.Add(rdb);
        }
        btn_fresh.Enabled = false;
        btn_next.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in pan_items.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
        {
            if (((RadioButton)ctrl).Checked)
                MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Name + " " + ctrl.Text + " is checked!");
            pan_items.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
            this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
            ctrl.Dispose();
        }
        this.index += 1;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string str in options[index])
        {
            RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
            rdb.Text = str;
            rdb.Name = str + "_" + i++;
            rdb.Location = new Point(20, i * 20);
            pan_items.Controls.Add(rdb);
        }
        btn_previous.Enabled = true;
    }
```

[image: The result after clicking fresh]
[image: The issue is highlighted]

What is wrong and how do i correct it?

Thanks so much, got the answer from the duplicate link. this code worked

```
private void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = pan_items.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Count() - 1; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            var ctrl = pan_items.Controls[j];
            if (((RadioButton)ctrl).Checked)
                MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Name + " " + ctrl.Text + " is checked!");
            pan_items.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
            this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
            ctrl.Dispose();
        }
        this.index += 1;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string str in options[index])
        {
            RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
            rdb.Text = str;
            rdb.Name = str + "_" + i++;
            rdb.Location = new Point(20, i * 20);
            pan_items.Controls.Add(rdb);
        }
        btn_previous.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: where is the portion of code that is responsible on removing controls?

Comment: @chouaib , the first part of the next click handler

Comment: You are removing items from a collection while looping through that collection. That could give bad results.

Comment: Why would you have to do  this.Controls.Remove(ctrl); ? You have instanciated and add the control dynamically into the panel. Why would you expect the framework to also add it directly in your form controls collection?

Comment: @alainlompo, that was my line of reasoning until i saw that it worked for someone on stackoverflow, so i decided to try it.

Comment: Assuming that options is an array of String arrays, I could reproduce your issue. If you are not using the panel to store other controls in it, then I suggest that you do pan_items.Controls.clear(). If you are using that panel to store other types of controls also I suggest that you split it in two smaller panels with one dedicated to your radio controls and do pan_items.Controls.clear()

Comment: can't you use pan_items.Controls.clear(); ?